# Iphone equivalent to Android <include> and <merge> tag?

Tags: android, iphone

I'm going to port an Android application over to the iPhone platform. I need header-footer like functionality so I'm looking for Android-style layouts merging for iPhone.

Does iPhone support this? If so, how?

[EDIT]

May be above header-footer description creating confusion.I am trying to describe again.

I would like to merge two different .xib file's view in single xib.for an example I have "footer.xib",I just want to include (reuse) same "footer.xib" view in different pages instead of copying same code for each page. I'm very new to Iphone world, so any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Android does things differently to iPhone with regards screen layouts. Not just from a technical way (ie how they are declared in code), but from a user interaction perspective they are different too. You would probably be better re-doing them from scratch on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd second the notion of going from scratch. I'd question why you'd need header functionality (UINavigationController provides a default header), but with the footer, do this:

Create a subclass of a UIView or UIToolbar or the like, and do custom drawing or custom layout in code. Then, place them in your views by dragging a UIView into a NIB/.XIB view controller file and changing the "Custom Class" field to that of your subclass, or programmatically add them.